# create a viewcontroller for each view screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Do you create a Viewcontroller per view screen? or should you share a viewcontrollers? (ie in the example below Should there be 3 controllers or just 1 controller?)

**Example** 
Screens are related

```
Screen1 (input information), 
Screen2 (Review and confirm Information), 
Screen3 (thank you / status response).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should code according to the MVC paradigm.  Parcel out your code and separate it based on overrarching function.  Here is a high level overview of MVC

(Data) Model: contains all of your app data, objects that are passed around and used to populate the views

View: everything that is some sort of visual output

Controller: Classes that make the models and views work together.

What this is saying, in iPhone development parlance, is don't just jam a bunch of code into your UIViewController subclass.  If you want to change the way part of the system works, having one huge class with a ton of code in it is a lot harder to edit and fix, than several smaller classes with a specialized use.

To answer your question, you should most definitely use one controller for each view function, but going beyond that, you should create specialized classes that take the inputs and manipulate that data, create specialized classes that then use the data to send it back to the user in an output.

Don't put all of your code into one class.  It might work, but if you ever need to tweak it, or, just like when the iPad came out, it has to be adapted to use on another platform, it will be easier to manage if you only have to change something small to make it work

Comment: lukya's answer gives a good possibility.  if you're not using separate detailed views, you can use one viewController to take input and then display output.  The important thing to consider is not to store all of the data processing in the viewController.  Use a distinct class that only processes incoming user data.  Don't do that inside your viewController.  The viewController can be updated with data from the data model.  If you ever have to mess with the data model it will be easier if you don't have to fish through a million lines of spaghetti code

Answer (score 1):

In your case you definitely don't need separate controllers. In fact you don't even need separate views. You can create a single view to take information, process it in the same controller and show the result in a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: That is possible.  It'd be important to not have all of the processing methods in the viewController.